# Flutter - Change AnimatedContainer height between 0 and null (Fit content)

Tags: flutter

From this,

```
AnimatedContainer(
    height : collapsed ? 0 : null,
)
```

Instead of the container animating the resizing, it shows this error during transition.

> Cannot interpolate between finite constraints and unbounded constraints. 'package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart': Failed assertion: line 484 pos 12: '(a.maxHeight.isFinite && b.maxHeight.isFinite) || (a.maxHeight == double.infinity && b.maxHeight == double.infinity)'

Which means I cannot change the container's height without explicitly set it first. Is there any other way to animate the change of the container's height between a content wrapping height and a finite height?